# Lanzar un un subproceso y al rotar dispositivo no se encuentra la referencia del componente visual Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-corrutinas

estoy haciendo un formulario con campos de texto y validación del campo mientras el usuario está entrado texto.

Uso la siguiente extención de Kotlin para poner un retardo mientras está escribiendo `debounce`

```kotlin
fun TextInputEditText.onChangeDebounce(duration: Long = 500L, cb: (String) -> Unit) {
    var lastStr = ""

    this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            val newStr = s.toString()
            if (newStr == lastStr)
                return

            lastStr = newStr

            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                delay(duration)
                if (newStr != lastStr)
                    return@launch

                cb(s.toString())
            }


        }
    })
}
```

Lo uso de la siguiente manera

```kotlin
edtField1.onChangeDebounce {
    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (!validatorFields.checkHomeName(it)) {
            til1.error = "Porfavor rellene el campo"
            requireContext().vibrate
        }
    }
}
```

Al estar introduciendo texto y al rotar el dispositivo, si se da en el tiempo del retardo de comprobación, se lanza y intenta hacer referencia al componente til1 `TextInputLayout`, obviamente la vista está destruida y me devuelve `NullReference` o a veces

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment RoomFragment{39245ca9} (0f921c89-f365-43cb-96bd-78d2f92ff3ed)} not attached to a context.

**Mi pregunta, es como se puede evitar eso?**

Lo primero que he probado es ejecutar cancelar en 'onPause'  el `job` con `job.cancelChildren()` pero no ha funcionado

He empezado hacer pruebas y lo único que me ha servido es poner un `if (!this.isResumed()) return` que comprueba si la vista no está en pantalla para cancelar la asignación del error en el objeto `TextInputLayout`

asi lo tengo

```
edtField1.onChangeDebounce {
    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (!this@RoomFragment.isResumed) return@withContext
        if (!validatorFields.checkHomeName(it)) {
            til1.error = "Porfavor rellene el campo"
            requireContext().vibrate
        }
    }
}
```

Hay alguna forma mejor de implementar eso?

Comment: Tambien me estoy mirando: http://solarex.github.io/blog/2016/02/25/android-handler-memory-leaks/

Comment: No inicies coroutines con `GlobalScope` de esa manera porque son imposibles de cancelar. Finalizan hasta que cierres la aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución me parece podría ser evitar se destruya y se cree nuevamente la actividad al rotar, agregando la propiedad a tu activity dentro del AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
                   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
```